# Can we do document to documents search using Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have a blob storage where i have list of word documents in it. I want search  a word document againest to blob storage and find matched documents. Can i use Azure Search for this? How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Search supports indexing blob storage. Please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage)

Comment: It is showing term based searching. in a term i can pass upto 32KB. Can i pass complete document for search in a search request? my documents are on average of 250-500KB.

Comment: Why do you want to pass a complete document to a search request? Usually a search query is relative short phrase or list of terms. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want find similer documents of my document. So i want to pass complete document.

Comment: Use [more like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-more-like-this) feature and pass the document id of the reference document.

Comment: Can you explain how can i pass the document here? I have seen specified link, what is 1002 in "Get /indexes/hotels/docs?moreLikeThis=1002&searchFields=description&api-version=2016-09-01-Preview"

Comment: It is just a sample document id. In case of blobs, by default the document id will be base-64 encoded value of blob path. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#how-azure-search-indexes-blobs

Comment: In general, please take a careful look at the documentation as this will help you with a bunch of your questions

Comment: Thank you for your info! I have 2 data sources one id blob and another one is SQL Azure database. for blob data source, it is very helpfull. How can perform search for relevent documents for SQL Azure data source?

Comment: For SQL datasource, you yourself control which column becomes the document key field.